# Symfony 6 - get session & doctrine interfaces from container

Tags: php, symfony

During upgrading Symfony 3.3 to Symfony 6.1 I found that a lot of my code within controllers is using '$this->container->get('session')' and '$this->container->get('doctrine')'.

The container is no longer a containerinterface, but a ServiceLocator object. Is there a way (maybe even through services.yaml?) to get the SessionInterface and the EntityMangerInterface directly from the ServiceLocator object?

I tried using a custom Controller (extended from AbstractController) to extend from. I could add the EntityMangerInterface, but I can no longer add the 'session' service, because it does not exist any longer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I mentioned in your previous question, making the jump from 3.3 to 6.1 is going to be challenging.  What you have encountered so far is just the tip of the iceberg.  The EntityManagerInterface should be injected.  As far as the session goes, the docs would be a good place to start.  Even in 3.3 the session service had significant problems.  These sorts of open ended questions are not a good fit for stackoverflow.  Might try the [Symfony Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/new/) board.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for your help! I'm continuing the jump from 3.3 to 6.1. I got quite a lot working already, but had to rewrite a lot. Also within the security part. Can I 'close' this question?